# VirtualBox не работает сеть после подключения Tor

Tags: virtualbox, linux-mint, tor

Я вообще не спец во всем этом. Думаю то что я делаю это вообще не то.
Но как я знаю, есть Whonix-Gateway, он работает через Tor. Сам я его проверял и Tor подключен.
На виртуальной машине, там где файлики. Я пытаюсь подключить Tor.

До начала в настройках сделал тип подключения: внутренняя сеть и имя Whonix.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И затем я виртуальной машине нажимаю на Edit Connections:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Потом делаю все что показано на скриншоте:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нажимаю на Wired Connection, после чего на шестеренку нажимаю. Далее делаю метод Manual и добавляю Address - 10.152.152.20, Netmask - 255.255.192.0, Gateway - 10.152.152.10. В DNS так же делаю 10.152.152.10. После чего нажимаю на Save и перезагружаю. Потом иду проверять, работает ли через Tor или нет.

Захожу в интернет, набираю адрес  - check.torproject.org и после чего жду. В итоге вообще не чего не работает, интернета нету.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Можете ли вы мне подсказать что делать в таком случаи? Может я что-то пропустил или иду вообще не по правильному пути? Был бы даже очень признателен если мне бы скинули статью или еще что-то, где показывают как можно завернуть все в tor и через него работать.

Comment: вот у вас текстом написано одно (т.е. правильно), а на картинке другое

Comment: перезагружать не обязательно, достаточно сделать down и up для интерфейса

Comment: также полезно на gateway запустить nyx и смотреть за трафиком и ошибками, и gateway советуют обновить сразу после установки apt update/upgrade

Comment: @PavelGridin, Здравствуйте, можете ли вы мне написать что именно на картинке не правильно? Возможно я забыл написать что когда в Netmask пишу — 255.255.192.0, то после сохранение у меня появляется просто цифра 18. Вчера смотрел, видел как у некоторых людей так же. Но у них все работает при этом. То что вы еще написал, попробую сделать. Спасибо вам за ответ!

Comment: @PavelGridin, Я был бы очень рад, можете ли вы подсказать как мне включить nyx в Gateway?

Comment: это текстовая программа, в терминале вводите `nyx` и у вас в DNS сервер 12 вместо 152, netmask понятно тогда